# Change datatype from factor to date

Tags: r, date, dataset, as.date

I have a dataset with dates.

`Class(dataset)` returns `"factor"`
Now I want to transform it into a dataset with dates. I use the `as.Date` function:

```
as.Date(dataset,  format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Now things gets weird. My data disappear. The dataset now contains `NA` values instead of dates

Look at this example:

```
eee<- c("2005-12-12", "2006-12-12", "2007-12-12")
eee
# [1] "2005-12-12" "2006-12-12" "2007-12-12"
class(eee)
# [1] "character"
fff<-as.Date(eee,  format = "%Y/%m/%d")
fff
# [1] NA NA NA

class(fff)
# [1] "Date"
```

Comment: share example data please

Comment: `as.Date(as.character(dataset), format = "%Y/%m/%d")` ?

Comment: the data comes from a csv file. it looks like this in the file: 2015-07-05 .... the colums around the dato file looks like this: (ID, Dato, Security type) : 753 2015-07-05 "BOND" ....

Comment: the transformation through character doesent work

Answer (score 0):

The format in `as.Date()` should match the format in character to be transformed e.g.

```
eee <- c("2005-12-12", "2006-12-12", "2007-12-12")
eee_date <-as.Date(as.character(eee),  format = "%Y-%m-%d")
class(eee_date)
```

Afterwards you can change the format by `format()` to your desired style.

```
eee_date <- format(eee_date, "%Y/%m/%d")
```